# How can I view permissions assigned to a Process Model's Identity in IIS?

Tags: iis

I need to ensure the Process Model's Identity is configured with the correct permissions.

Is there a way for me to view these?

Comment: these what? the permissions or the application pool identities?

Comment: The permissions

Comment: well, permissions are on file resources, so you just check the permissions on the file resources the app pool worker process will access. In IIS you can ask it to test site permissions, under the appliations basic settings dialog.

Comment: What version of IIS are you referring to? I'm looking on Version 7.5 and I don't see any option to test it.

Comment: Two links to check 1.) https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/processmodel and 2.) http://serverfault.com/questions/346777/iis-7-5-folder-and-web-site-permissions